# How to push to GitHub protected branch via sbt-release plugin?

Tags: github, sbt, sbt-release

TL;DR:
What is the correct workflow to use both `sot-release` plugin with GitHub protected branch?

I'm using `sot-release` plugin in order to auto-increment the project version files, and to commit it to the `main` branch.
In addition, I would like to set the `main` branch as a GitHub protected branch.

In order to do it, I've created a GitHub token for the CI flow and grant it with push permissions.

The flow works as follows: once a PR is reviewed and merged to `main` (the protected branch), more tests are executed in GitHub Actions and the final step is to call `sbt` task for creating a release. This task is using `sot-release` plugin in order to push changes of version file in the repository.

However, the CI flow is not able to push the changes to the protected branch:

```
[info] remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/master.        
49
[info] remote: error: 3 of 3 required status checks are expected.        
50
[info] To https://github.com/piplcom/dap-test
51
[info]  ! [remote rejected] master -> master (protected branch hook declined)
```

What is the correct workflow? What am I missing in here?

Answer (score 1):

As described in "[How to resolve GH006 Protected Branch Update Failed](https://www.paulmowat.co.uk/blog/resolve-github-action-gh006-protected-branch-update-failed)" from [Paul Mowat](https://www.paulmowat.co.uk/about), a solution would be to use a dedicated account with a token:

- Create a new Github user specifically for building.
- Create a new personal access token for that user with access to repo.
- Add the personal access token as a Github secret e.g. BUILD_SVC_PAT.
- Update your branch protection and add your new build user to 'Restrict who can push to matching branches'.
- Update your Github action to check out the code using the Github secret.

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checking out...
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.BUILD_SVC_PAT }}
```

---

The [OP matan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5753936/matan) has already done that, but adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72168123/how-to-push-to-github-protected-branch-via-sbt-release-plugin/72168597?noredirect=1#comment127515338_72168597):

> it was my bad: We use the [`sbt-github-actions` plugin](https://github.com/djspiewak/sbt-github-actions) and missed setting the GitHub token in the publish stage as well.
> It now works as expected!

Comment: Thank you @VonC for your response. I've already tried that but still getting the same error.
Anything else to share?

Comment: @Matan Strange. maybe the token is not correctly created? Or for a user without proper access? If not, check if this might have any effect on your situation: https://github.blog/changelog/2022-05-03-github-actions-prevent-github-actions-from-creating-and-approving-pull-requests/

Comment: Solved this issue, it was my bad. We use `sbt-github-actions` plugin and  missed setting the github token in the publish stage as well. It now works as expected! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Matan Great, well done! I have edited the answer to include your comment as well as relevant link.